# How to create an app in android that find places nearest your location

Tags: android, database, dictionary, geolocation

I'm trying to create a geolocation app in android. So far i've been able to locate my current location and have it display on a map. Now i want to get a list of places the are nearest to my location. I know i will have to save the data in a database, and somehow check against it. Trouble is i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you intend to store a database on the Android?

Unless you have a very restricted location like a college campus, I think you might find that you don't have enough storage.

You don't tell us what you application is, so it's difficult to help precisely, but I would suggest that want to query publicly available datababses which are online for features of interest near to you and display those. As your location changes you would thnen have to re-query the databases.

I highly recommend Google maps which integrates well with Google Android and which provides some of this functionality for you.

A good book to get started is [Map Scripting 101](http://mapscripting.com/book). There is also lots of good information at the website.

Hope this helps.